Per quale ragione alcuni dicono "una ipotesi", "una intervista" invece di "un'ipotesi", "un'intervista"?
Normalmente «una» diventa «un’» davanti a vocale, ma ho visto più volte «una» davanti a vocale, senza elisione:
Esempi a caso trovati sul web:

«una intervista», «Nanni Moretti: Una Intervista»
«una ipotesi»
«una operazione»
«una ubiquità»

Come mai?

L'elisione non è obbligatoria per l'articolo “una”. Per citare l'Enciclopedia dell'italiano Treccani,

Una invece, che normalmente si elide (un’amica, un’improvvisa febbre), può essere lasciata integra per scelta individuale: una improvvisa febbre, una astrazione” (https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/elisione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/).

Quindi in definitiva si tratta di una scelta individuale di chi ha scritto i testi che citi.
